# Create RDS full access role inside AWS SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-sam

I am trying to access RDS mysql database via lambda function. I am deploying as SAM template. I have a lambda function attached to an execution role as the following:

```
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - rds:*
                Resource: "*"

  CreateTaskFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./components/lambdaFunctions/createTask
      Handler: createTask.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Timeout: 500
      Events:
        ProxyApiRoot:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
            Path: /
            Method: ANY
        ProxyApiGreedy:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: ANY
      Layers:
        - !Ref NodeModulesLayer
```

After deploying the stack the lambda can't connect to RDS, and I found only the cloudwatch logs roles in the permission section of lambda:
[image]

As you see the RDS permission is not listed. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "the lambda can't connect to RDS"? Are you referring to making SQL queries? Can you show us the code and the error message? Is the code authenticating to the database using a username and password, or with IAM credentials? Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein, I figured it out it was a VPC issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh my bad. I figured it out, it was a VPC issue. Lambda has to be attached to a VPC, and a security group that is allowed by the security group of the database.